# Cordova android platform installation fails with error : Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli, cordova-plugin-proguard

We have automated scripts for installing the cordova plugins and installing all the cordova platforms and finally to build the binaries. The setup used for from long time. From today the builds started failing while installing the android platform with error **Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...**.

Log :

```
Creating android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms\android
    Package: com.diona.mobility.clientApplication
    Name: Client Application
    Android target: android-19
Copying template files...
Running: android update project --subprojects --path "platforms\android" --target android-19 --library "CordovaLib"
Resolved location of library project to: E:\Products\Worksapce\dimas\build\clients\ClientApplication\full\cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib
Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using Activity name 'ClientApplication'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file E:\Products\Worksapce\dimas\build\clients\ClientApplication\full\cordova\platforms\android\build.xml
Added file E:\Products\Worksapce\dimas\build\clients\ClientApplication\full\cordova\platforms\android\proguard-project.txt
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using project folder name 'CordovaLib'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file E:\Products\Worksapce\dimas\build\clients\ClientApplication\full\cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.xml
Added file E:\Products\Worksapce\dimas\build\clients\ClientApplication\full\cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\proguard-project.txt

Project successfully created.
Installing "com.phonegap.plugin.mobile-accessibility" for android
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git" via git clone
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git" via git clone
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for android
Installing "com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh" for android
Installing "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" for android
Installing "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
```

Is anyone aware of this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting few hours found that this build failures are because of dependency changes in latest com.phonegap.plugin.mobile-accessibility plugin. Removing this plugin resolved the error(Had no other option as there is no previous tagged working version for the same plugin).

Answer (score 1):

i think there is something wrong with the cordova Plugins. Like it is described in this Post: [Broken BarcodeScanner Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23971060/3671726) i would say that the issue is about sth. with the Plugins.

You say that all worked fine for weeks, so i wouldn't worry about your script. The solution which worked for the other user was to copy the plugin from gitHub and install it from the local path.

```
git clone https://github.com/pathtoplugin.git

cd to your Cordova project.

Cordova plugin add InsertPath\BarcodeScanner
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But here the problem is the log doesnt contain any info about the plugin which is causing the issue and I have around 20+ plugins in my project. I will try to narrow down the issue to specific plugin and post the update.